# Error uploading from Laravel 5.4 to S3 bucket

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3, upload

[I run the script from localhost]

I'm trying to upload files using Laravel 5.4 to AWS S3 bucket but I get this error:

```
Error executing "PutObject" on "https://bucket_name.s3.amazonaws.com/1520719994357906.png"; AWS HTTP error: cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)
```

In filesystems.php:

```
's3' => [
        'driver' => 's3',
        'key' => 'KRY_HERE',
        'secret' => 'SECRET_HERE',
        'region' => 'us-east-1',
        'bucket' => 'bucket_name', //has global access to read files
    ],
```

In the controller:

```
Storage::disk('s3')->put($imageName, file_get_contents(public_path('galleries/').$imageName));
```

How to solve this? If I upload the app to EC2 instance does it require SSL installed to upload files to S3 bucket? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Uploading from server worked fine no need to install SSL it just doesn't work from localhost.

Answer (score 0):

it just doesn't work from localhost,if you want to do working it on localhost you have to do some changes in vendor directory.(For your local use only)

> vendor/guzzle/src/handler/CurlFactory.php

Near around line no 350.Comment this two line and add new two line,otherwise replace this two line.(as you wish)

```
  if ($options['verify'] === false) {
                    unset($conf[\CURLOPT_CAINFO]);
                    $conf[\CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST] = 0;
                    $conf[\CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER] = false;
                } else {
               /* $conf[\CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST] = 2;
                  $conf[\CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER] = true;*/ //Comment this two line
                  $conf[\CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST] = 0;
                  $conf[\CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER] = false;
}
```

Now it's work fine.